# Wordpress - remove last Comma from output with rtrim

Tags: php, wordpress, syntax-error, taxonomy

I've got the following code which is a part of the widget that outputs the terms of the taxonomy 'season'

The taxonomy terms are output with space and comma in between them, but it also adds a comma at the very end.

How can I get rid off the last comma?

```
echo $args['before_widget'];
if ( ! empty( $title ) )
echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];

global $post;  
$tags = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'season' );

if( $tags ) : ?>

 <?php foreach( $tags as $tag ) :

  $tag_link = esc_url( get_term_link( $tag ) );
  $tag_output = '';
  $tag_output .= '<a href="' . $tag_link . '" class="listing-tag">';        
  $tag_output .= '<span class="tag__text">' . $tag->name . '</span></a>';
  $tag_output .=", ";

  echo $tag_output;

  endforeach; ?>

 <?php endif;

echo $args['after_widget'];
}
```

I'been trying to use the `rtrim($tag_output,', ');` but I just can't figure out where to put this `rtrim` string, to make this working.

Where in the code should the `rtrim($tag_output,', ');` sit to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be easier to [map your array](http://php.net/manual/function.array-map.php) to one containing the strings you want and then display it using [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.implode.php). For example

```php
if ($tags) {
    $tagOutput = array_map(function($tag) {
        return sprintf(
               '<a href="%s" class="listing-tag"><span class="tag__text">%s</span></a>',
                esc_url( get_term_link( $tag ) ),
                $tag->name
        );
    }, $tags);

    echo implode(', ', $tagOutput);
}

echo $args['after_widget'];
```